# mysql - query to remove multiple characters from column content

Tags: mysql, replace

Can I create a query using "replace" to remove more than one character\string from a column content ?

For example I have:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, '\r\n', '');
```

But what if I want to remove multiple characters or strings like:

```
<br />
<&nbsp>
<\r>
```

Is it possible to run this in  single query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cascade it

```
UPDATE table1 
SET column1 = replace(replace(REPLACE(column1, '\r\n', ''), '<br />',''), '<\r>','')
```